# "they've misunderstood" or "they've been misunderstood"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction

> How can they trust it, they've **been** misunderstood

I'm not sure whether **been** should be there or not.

Comment: "Have" is already there in "they've" but the question is unclear. The title asks something else.

Comment: They've = **they have** :)

Comment: Yeah, I see. I wrote wrong body. Edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*They've misunderstood* is **active**: they are the ones who have done the misunderstanding.

*They've been misunderstood* is **passive**: somebody else has misunderstood them.

Both grammatical, both perfectly natural, and utterly different in meaning.

Comment: have done, I've said....

Comment: Absolutely, @Lambie. Don't know how I missed that. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

**They've = They have**.
So I would just say **They've misunderstood**, otherwise you'd say "have" twice and it doesn't have much sense.

Comment: Sorry, I was in hurry so I wrote wrong body. It's edited now. It should make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The two mean different things! So which to use depends on what you want to say:

**They've been misunderstood** means someone else has misunderstood 'them'. In other words, if I say something, and you misunderstand me, then I **have been misunderstood**.

**They misunderstood** means that the people we mean by "they" are doing the misunderstanding: If I say something, and you misunderstand me, **you misunderstood**

"I misunderstood" is *past tense*, and "active voice", the speaker is doing something.

"I have been misunderstood" is *past perfect tense*, and "passive voice", something is being done to the speaker by someone else.

I think in the context of your sentence" "How can they trust it, they misunderstood. They don't understand what it means."

Comment: Your description at the beginning is correct, but your grammatical description concentrates on a difference of tense that wasn't there in the original question, and ignores the difference of voice: active vs. passive.